# netty file upload with auth ,if the auth failed ,how can i discard the left httpConent?

Tags: netty

i'm using netty to dev a file upload server  , when  a client upload a file , it needs contains  the auth info like a token which put in the form body before any file . if the token is  mismatch, the server return an error code and close the channel, My problem is how can i discarded the left HttpConent data？I've seen the netty file upload demo,but i can't get the answer。

Comment: netty.version>4.1.52.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of 2 choices :

1. consume all data whatever is going on and just ignore those contents, then send the response : inconvenient, you have to wait for all data to come in
2. send the response immediately when you know it's over (failed authentication) with something like:

   ```
   final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(response); // (1)
   f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE); // (2)
   ```

(1) Flush your answear (in error)

(2) When the answear is sent, close the context, so the channel, so the connexion.

- Advantage: this stops immediately the receive operation
- Disadvantage: but you probably will have to store in the session of this connexion that this one is in error since more buffers could be already arrived or on going to cime, and `channelRead` can be called even after the (1) before (2) occurs. So you will have to silently ignored those new buffers in this case.

Something like:

```
private boolean inError = false;

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf m = (ByteBuf) msg;
    if (inError) {
      msg.release();
      return;
    }
    ...
    if (!isTokenOk(token)) {
      inError = true;
      ... build your response in error
      final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
      f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
      return;
    }
    ... continue with other part of buffers
 }
```

Note that from client perspective, if it doesn't have sent all data, it might ends with a "too early closed connection" if it doesn't handle to receive an answer before ending to send its own body.

Also note that generally, Token are in Header part, not body part... But this depends on your implementation.